# LwIP Lightweight IP - pbuf_alloc returns null. PBUF_POOL_IS_EMPTY

Tags: c, tcp, lwip

I am currently using [lwIP](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/lwip/) on a Freescale K60 project to aid our Ethernet TCP implementation with the following options set in lwipopts.h.

```
#define MEM_SIZE                (12*1024)

/* MEMP_NUM_PBUF: the number of memp struct pbufs. If the application
   sends a lot of data out of ROM (or other static memory), this
   should be set high. */
#define MEMP_NUM_PBUF           10
/* MEMP_NUM_UDP_PCB: the number of UDP protocol control blocks. One
   per active UDP "connection". */
#define MEMP_NUM_UDP_PCB        6
/* MEMP_NUM_TCP_PCB: the number of simulatenously active TCP
   connections. */
#define MEMP_NUM_TCP_PCB        10
/* MEMP_NUM_TCP_PCB_LISTEN: the number of listening TCP
   connections. */
#define MEMP_NUM_TCP_PCB_LISTEN 6
/* MEMP_NUM_TCP_SEG: the number of simultaneously queued TCP
   segments. */
#define MEMP_NUM_TCP_SEG        12
/* MEMP_NUM_SYS_TIMEOUT: the number of simulateously active timeouts. */
#define MEMP_NUM_SYS_TIMEOUT    10

/* ---------- Pbuf options ---------- */
/* PBUF_POOL_SIZE: the number of buffers in the pbuf pool. */
#define PBUF_POOL_SIZE          10

/* PBUF_POOL_BUFSIZE: the size of each pbuf in the pbuf pool. */
#define PBUF_POOL_BUFSIZE       1518
```

I have experienced an issue where the first 9 messages from a PC client to the device have been successfully read and passed up to an application level, on the 10th attempt however this fails and we do not receive any more messages over the ethernet connection.

After chasing this down I have found that inside of pbuf.c, I am receiving a `PBUF_POOL_IS_EMPTY()` due to the call of

```
(struct pbuf *)memp_malloc(MEMP_PBUF_POOL); returning NULL.
```

Further inspection shows that the values of `memp_tab` are as follows post issue

```
-memp_tab[0] 0x1FFF4160 </br>
-memp_tab[1] 0x1FFF421C </br>
-memp_tab[2] 0x1FFF423C </br>
-memp_tab[3] 0x1FFF4364 </br>
-memp_tab[4] 0x1FFF4478 </br>
-memp_tab[5] 0x1FFF450C </br>
-memp_tab[6] 0x1FFF467C </br>
-memp_tab[7] 0x1FFF46D4 </br>
-memp_tab[8] 0x1FFF4744 </br> 
-memp_tab[9] 0x00000000 </br>
```

The Value of `memp_tab[9]` is a worry.

This all seems to me like our memory is not being re-allocated after use despite our inclusion of the memp_malloc call. Is there any way we can re-allocate this memory after use, in the call which will allow us to use the function for more than the declared use.

Comment: PBUF_POOL is intended to be used for received packets.  I'm unfamiliar with your driver/port, so I can't say for sure if that's what is consuming the memory.  What API are you using in your application (it seems like received buffers are not being free)?

Comment: May be you simply don't free previous buffer with `pbuf_free()`? Refer to examples. They could help. To achieve good answer you should share your code. And read carefully [LwIP Wiki](http://lwip.wikia.com/wiki/LwIP_Wiki)